# Android Studio: The following classes could not be instantiated: - androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-studio

I am currently learning Android Studio and ran into an issue in the activity_main.xml, where i cannot view then buttons, text and etc. (See image Link).

[Link to Andoird Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYNi.png)

I am also getting following error:

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure$Measurer Copy stack to clipboard

I did try to build the project and update dependencies without success.

The XML code is:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="393dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="393dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="657dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I have following implementation:

`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'`

Comment: Did solve the issue? please share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the added dependency for constraint layout use the below:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```